# UiLifecycleHelper cannot be resolved to a type in facebook android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

How can I do this?

I am facing some error for UiLifecycleHelper class. I am using `facebook-android-sdk-3.0.2.b`.

At the line:

```
private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
```

I am facing error:

> UiLifecycleHelper cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: Any errors in the LogCat ?

Comment: no logcat still , because i havent run app . it gives an error while writing code. i tried import(ctrl+shift+o) but it doesnt work for UiLifecycleHelper.

Answer (score 2):

I think the UI Helper was added in the release version of the SDK and wasn't in the beta. Download version 3.0.1 [here](https://developers.facebook.com/android/). That should let you import the class.

Comment: Sorry, the link you followed may be broken, or the page may have been removed.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Facebook Android SDK 3.x use the latest one `3.23.1` ([3.x changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/change-log-3.x)). Also you can directly use maven repo. Make following changes in app level gradle file -

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.23.1'
}
```

And you should be good to go.

If you are using Facebook Android SDK 4.x or upgrading from 3.x to 4.x then make a note that

> CallbackManager.onActivityResult replaces Session.onActivityResult and UiLifecycleHelper.onActivityResult. See Facebook Login for Android, Register a Callback.

So you won't find `UiLifecycleHelper` class there. More details - [Upgrading the Android SDK from 3.x to 4.x](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/upgrading-4.x)